# How do I pass CommaDelimitedList parameters to nested stacks in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Ran into the following error when we call child module from the parent module in aws.
"Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties".

Parent.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
 DirsToCreate:
   Type: List<String>
   Default: "test/injury_code,testing/cmd_injury_code,upload/exclusion"
   Description: "Comma delimited directories to create."

  ExportedSecretValue:
    Type: String
    Description: Glue Data Load db user's credential

  dataLoadType:
    Type: String
    Default: icd
    Description: Specify the type of data load

  prefix:
    Type: String
    Default: test/checking
    Description: S3 Key value 

Resources:
  IcdData:
    Type: VN::Glue::Test::MODULE
    Properties:
      DirsToCreate: !Join
        - ','
        - !Ref DirsToCreate
      dataLoadType: !Ref dataLoadType
      prefix: !Ref prefix
      ExportedSecretValue: !Ref ExportedSecretValue
```

Nested-stack.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  DirsToCreate:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: "Comma delimited list of directories to create."

  dataLoadType:
    Type: String
    Description: Specify the type of data load ICD or DCD

  prefix:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 Key value for ICD or DCD

  ExportedSecretValue:
    Type: String
    Description: Glue Data Load db user's credential

Resources:
 S3CustomResource:
   Type: Custom::S3CustomResource
   Properties:
     ServiceToken: !GetAtt CreateS3FoldersLambda.Arn
     the_bucket: !Ref DataS3Bucket
     dirs_to_create: !Ref DirsToCreate
```

Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) to join your `CommaDelimitedList` to string with delimiter of comma to pass it as string.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?